# Icon or image in center with line on both sides

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create some CSS to have a icon or image in the center with a line on both sides, but it seems like i'm doing something wrong and need some help.

For simplicity I just use a star character in the code.

```
<div class='line-container'><div class='line-icon'>*</div></div>

.line-icon {
text-align: center;
}

.line-icon::before {
width: 25%;
height: 1px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.line-icon::after {
width: 25%;
height: 1px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us an image of what you want to achieve, and possibly post your code via JSFiddle or similar?

Comment: Is an image really necessary!? This is a very common thing om web pages. A centered icon and then lines on both sides.

Comment: Like [this image](http://imgur.com/b3eDpKs)?

Comment: instead of using :before  or :after... use border-width: 0px 1px 0px 1px. The order is clockwise: top, right, bottom, left

Comment: @citelao Yes, something like that!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mknjjtvx/

Comment: @Liquidchrome Nice, but I was looking for horizontal lines

Comment: then switch them up to 1px 0px 1px 0px

Comment: @Liquidchrome, thanks, but then I get a long line above and below. Not what I was looking for, but thanks for your effort!

Comment: Necessary, no, but helpful yes. It doesn't take a lot more time for you to find an image and add it to your post, and we know exactly what you want to achieve - there's no risk of someone spending time finding a solution to the wrong problem. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a content to your `::after` and `::before`, and setting its display:

```css
.line-icon {
    text-align: center;
}

/* Joined both selectors, since were pretty much the same */
.line-icon::before,
.line-icon::after {      
    /* Styles kept */
    width: 25%;
    height: 1px;

    /* Changed to border-top (instead of border) to simulate a line better */
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc; 

    /* Styles added */
    display: inline-block;
    content: '';
  
    /* Use padding to vertical align the line */
    /* Use padding in em for a responsive icon height */
    padding-top: 0.5em; 
  
    /* Use margins to give the lines some spacement around the icon */
    /* Use margins in % for a responsive spacement */
    margin-left: 5%; 
    margin-right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class='line-container'><div class='line-icon'>*</div></div>
```

Comment: Nice, but would it also be possible to have some padding around the icon and also vertical align the line to the middle?

Comment: @3D-kreativ I've updated my answer: you can control the vertical alignment to middle with padding, and you can add padding around the icon by setting a margin.

Comment: Much better! I guess there should not be any problem to use an image instead of this character. If the image are higher I adjust the padding for the vertical align then? And for the responsive layout, I just change the width of the border in % ?

Comment: @3D-kreativ I've updated my answer: you can control responsiveness better by setting styles in `em` and `%` units.

Answer (score 2):

A different style but may be usefull for u

```css
.seperator {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}
.seperator:after {
  content: "vs";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.7em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 0 0.50em;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<hr class="seperator"></hr>
```

Comment: This also seems to be very useful! Thanks!